# How to NOT persist state between Next.js dynamic routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm building a headless eCommerce site using React/Next and have a `[product].js` dynamic route which is used to generate all product pages, using `getStaticPaths()` and `getStaticProps()` which generates the pages fine.

I'm using `useState` hook within `[product].js` to manage a number input (for quantity) and a couple of other things.

The first product page loaded works fine, but when I go to other product pages, they use the same state from the first product.

Is there a way to have the state NOT persist between route changes?

Through some digging, I found that this is an issue with next and is in their backlog. It essentially stems from the fact that the component doesn't have a key. This means switching between routes on the same dynamic route doesn't register correctly and causes the component to use stale state.

A possible solution I found was this:

```
export async function getStaticProps({params}) {
    const props = await getData(params);

    // key is needed here
    props.key = data.id; 

    return {
        props: props
    }
}
```

This is my implementation which doesn't work for me:

```
export default function ProductPage(props) {

  // this state doesn't reset between dynaic route changes
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1)

  return(
    ...
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const slug = params.product
  const props = await client.query({
    query: singleProductQuery,
    variables: { id: slug }
  })

  props.key = props.data.product.slug

  return {
    props: props
  }
}
```

I tried wrapping the contents within another component and adding a key to that, like so:

```
return(
  <OuterComponent key={props.id}>
    // components within here, that have their own state, now work
  </OuterComponent>
)
```

Since this new keyed component is only in the return statement and does not encapsulate the state hook, it does not work. This does reset the state however, for any components found within wrapped component.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `useEffect` hook and `useRoute`r hook at dynamic router to reset the state.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

const ProductPage = (props) => {
const [state, setState] = useState(someState)
const dynamicRoute = useRouter().asPath
useEffect(() => {
  setState(resetState) // When the dynamic route change reset the state
}, [dynamicRoute])
//Some other logic
return (
......
)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you've encountered the same issue thread that I've found:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9992

It seems from what I've read that to fix your case, all you need to do is change your `getStaticProps` to return an object with a unique key:

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const slug = params.product
  const props = await client.query({
    query: singleProductQuery,
    variables: { id: slug }
  });

  return {
    props: props,
    key: slug
  }
}
```

What you've been doing previously is passing a key to the props object instead of root return object for `getStaticProps`

Comment: I had thought of this but it seems at odds with the point of SSG. I also store currently visible reviews in state and I'm worried having the state set after page load could be detrimental to SEO. I can use onChange events rather than state, but I thought I'd first look into a stateful approach. Also, is there a reason for returning a function within useEffect, rather than simply calling setQuantity directly in the first enclosed function?

Comment: I tried to implement this solution just for quantity but useEffect doesn't fire when switching between dynamic routes. I went ahead and added more detail to my question too.

Comment: I'll try and look into it. But seeing your page code would help a lot. Also if you have custom _App or _Document, show it as well. However it does seem more like a next bug with his you describe it

Comment: I'll add more detailed code in the initial question and explain where I'm at. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I forgot to mention. Dynamic route changes, within the same dynamic route, also don't trigger useEffect. use Effect only fires on the first load, or when routing to the dynamic route from a different route.

Comment: I've updated my answer and it should work from what I've seen.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I'd already tried that and it doesn't work. Next throws the error: "Additional keys were returned from `getStaticProps`. Properties intended for your component must be nested under the `props` key." It seems like I might be out of luck and will simply have to avoid using state within the top-level dynamic route component and simply nest this functionality within returned components and add keys to them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use useEffect hook to reset state

```
export default function ProductPage(props) {



// this state doesn't reset between dynaic route changes
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1)

  useEffect(() => {
    setQuantity(props.quantity) // <-- this props comes from getStaticProps
}, [props]) // <--- useEffect will keep tracking changing props



  return(
    ...
  )
}
```

So when your props changes - your state updates.